# missing keyword error for jpa native query

Tags: spring-data-jpa

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM  wiz_deals INNER JOIN wiz_preferences p ON 1 = 1 INNER JOIN wiz_publish_invoice ON wiz_deals.invoice_id = wiz_publish_invoice.invoice_id WHERE  wiz_deals.total_inv_remain_amt BETWEEN p.INV_AMT_MIN=?INV_AMT_MIN AND p.INV_AMT_MAX=?INV_AMT_MAX AND  wiz_deals.credit_period BETWEEN p.TENURE_MIN=?TENURE_MIN AND p.TENURE_MAX=?TENURE_MAX ",nativeQuery=true)


public List<Deals> findByPrefrenceSorting(@Param("INV_AMT_MIN") int INV_AMT_MIN,@Param("INV_AMT_MAX") int INV_AMT_MAX,@Param("TENURE_MIN") int TENURE_MIN,@Param("TENURE_MAX") int TENURE_MAX);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, I just modified some thing

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Deals wiz_deals INNER JOIN wiz_preferences p 
ON 1 = 1 INNER JOIN wiz_publish_invoice ON wiz_deals.invoice_id    
=wiz_publish_invoice.invoice_id WHERE  wiz_deals.total_inv_remain_amt 
BETWEEN :INV_AMT_MIN AND :INV_AMT_MAX AND wiz_deals.credit_period BETWEEN 
:TENURE_MIN AND :TENURE_MAX ",nativeQuery=true)


public List<Deals>findByPrefrenceSorting(@Param("INV_AMT_MIN") int INV_AMT_MIN,@Param("INV_AMT_MAX") int INV_AMT_MAX,@Param("TENURE_MIN") int TENURE_MIN,@Param("TENURE_MAX") int TENURE_MAX);
```